# How to add a new "<location path=" with all settings to web.config programatically C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

How to add a new `<location path=` with all settings to web.config programatically C#?
I have a form in which is a TextBox and a Button on which when i click it gets the textbox text, and creates in web.config:

```
<location path=" <-- TextBox.Text -->">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net does not allow to change web.config diagrammatically, however you can change it by using file io classes which is not preferred way.

You can make a setting xml file and use it for reading/writing your setting from code.

Comment: Ow... I read the same on web, but thoght maybe it can be done somehow not using file io. :( thx